# Making of new record and showing it inside a div (append to a while loop)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to to make a form that will submit a new record and automatically show that as DIV inside of the main DIV and after all the results from the PHP while loop.

Here is the while loop that I've built:

```
<?php 
while ($row_apps = mysql_fetch_array($result_apps))
{
    if ( ($row_apps['type'] == 'ar') && ($row_apps['client'] == NULL) ) {
echo '<center>
<div id="_'.$row_apps['app_id'].'" class="tab_listing">
<table width="248" border="0" cellspacing="10px" cellpadding="0px">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%" colspan="3"><div class="tab_listing_header">'.$row_apps['app_name'].'</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="tab_listing_values"><b>App ID: </b>'.$row_apps['app_id'].'</td>
    <td class="tab_listing_values"><b>Users: </b>'.$row_apps['users'].'</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="edit">Edit</div>
<a href="#" onclick="return show_confirm('.$row_apps['app_id'].')"><div id="delete"></div></a>
</div>
</center><br>';
} 
}
?>
```

Now basically what i need to do is when a form is submitted and the new record is in the database i want it to show a new "block" exact same like the while "blocks" live.

I was thinking about something like:

```
$.post("create.php",{ value1:$('#value1').val(),value2:$('value2').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
        {
          if(data=='yes')
          {
HERE I'M STUCK.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$.post("create.php",{ value1:$('#value1').val(),value2:$('value2').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
        {
          if(data)
          {
            $("mainDivSelector").html(data);
          }
);
```

Comment: What does (data) mean? i mean how it will display the exact same box in the needed place if create.php will only insert the new record to the db? or should i replace "yes" with the actual code i want to add to the list?

Comment: data is the response provided by `create.php` page which is basically the markyp you are echoing.

Comment: `if(data)` will check for not null and empty condition. If you want to check for something else you can change it.

Answer (score 1):

**data** will contain a result string returned by create.php and that is entirely up to you.  What does create.php do at the moment?

Comment: it only makes the new record (single mysql query) and then if its ok it returns "yes". Is the answer of the previous guy is an "add" or it will just replace all the current info in #mainDivSelector ?

Comment: He's missing a # in the selector, but .html() sets the content of the container, which means any previous content will be lost.  You need .append() instead.